# error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'double')

Tags: c

***THIS IS THE QUESTION***

> Write a program to find out whether a number is kaprekar or not.
> Consider an n-digit number k. Square it and add the right n digits to
> the left n or n-1 digits. If the resultant sum is k, then k is called
> a Kaprekar number. For example, 9 is a Kaprekar number since
>
> 9^2=81 and  8+1=9
>
> and 297 is a Kaprekar number since
>
> 297^2=88209 and 88+209=297
> *this is the code i have written*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int k,num,j=0,rev,act,s,rem;

    while(num!=0){
        num=k/(pow(10,j));
        if(num==0){
            rev=j;
        }
        else{
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
    rem=num%(pow(10,(j/2)));
    act=num/(pow(10,(j/2)));
    s=rem+act;
    if(s=num){
        printf("This is a Kaprekar number: ");
    }
    else{
        printf("This isnt a Kaprekar number: ");
    }
}
```

the error that shows is:

```
Karpekar.c: In function 'main':
Karpekar.c:16:12: error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'double')
     rem=num%(pow(10,(j/2)));
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PS C:\Users\shaun\OneDrive\Desktop\c programming\programs>
```

Someone please help

Comment: yep need to use modulus operator with int only. pow() gives double I think

Comment: `while(num!=0){` - Where is `num` initialised

Answer (score -1):

The `%` operator is explicitly defined to return the integer remainder, so you cannot use it with operands that are floating point. `pow()` returns `double`.

You either have to cast that result to an integer type or use `fmod()` to get the floating-point remainder.